# Qual a diferença entre init e constructor?

Tags: kotlin

Estou começando a aprender Kotlin e gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre `init` e `constructor`, ou definir diretamente na classe exemplo:

```
class House(var cor: String, var vagaGaragem: Int)
```

Comment: A resposta esclareceu a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, isso que você chama de "definir direto na classe" **é um construtor**.

Uma classe em Kotlin pode ter um construtor primário e construtores "secundários".

Construtores primários são como este do seu código de exemplo: ele é seguido do nome da classe e pode ter parâmetros. Estes não podem ter um bloco de código, então, a única forma de escrever algum código de inicialização neles é usando o bloco **`init`**.

Além disto, todos os blocos de inicialização definidos na classe serão executados para **todos os construtores** na ordem que forem criados.

Veja um exemplo:

```
fun main() {    
    var p = Person("Jeferson", 23)

    println("**************")

    var p2 = Person("Joaquim")
}

class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) { // <<= Construtor primário
    constructor(name: String) : this(name, 0) {  // <<= Construtor secundário
        println("Construtor 2")
    }

    init {
        println("Init 1")
    }

    init {
        println("Bloco Init 2")
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Kotlin Playground**](https://pl.kotl.in/SkeAEcv_E)</sup>

Isso vai imprimir na tela

> ```
> Init 1  
> Bloco Init 2  
> **************  
> Init 1  
> Bloco Init 2  
> Construtor 2
> ```

Comment: Como assim, os construtores primários não podem ter código? Gostaria de entender, não tem código no próprio construtor usado como exemplo?

Comment: @user140828 Que código? Não tem nada lá.

Comment: `println` não é considerado código? Acho que entendi errado, construtor primário seria a própria declaração da classe?

Comment: @user140828 Pus um comentário para identificar cada construtor

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre o `init` e o `constructor` é no que diz respeito ao byte code não muito diferente. Mas para poder perceber a diferença temos que partir do principio de que entendemos o que é um contructor primário.

### Construtor primário

Em Kotlin, o constutor primário é, em linguagem comum, aquele que não se vê. No exemplo que apresentas, um objecto to tipo `House` é inicializado com `cor` e com `vagaGaragem`. Aqui hà um problema. Esta inicialização é feita com variáveis mutáveis. Em Kotlin é boa práctica usar `val` em vez de `var` sempre que obviamente seja possível. Este construtor permite que estas propriedades sejam alteradas mais tarde. Para podermos falar do seguinte tema, construtores secundários, temos que entender muito bem a diferença entre `val` e `var`.

### Construtor secundário

O construtor secundário permite adicionar outros construtores para criar os nossos objects. No entanto, todos eles acabam por ter que usar o construtor primário, pois este define o contrato primário de construção do objecto. No caso de utilizarmos proprieddes imutáveis como `val` isto também não é problem, pois o construtor secundário apenas vai construir o objecto e fazer única e exclusivamente uma assignação por propriedade. Neste exemplo, podemos inicializar um object to tipo `House` com apenas uma `String`:

```
class ImmutableHouse(val cor: String, var vagaGaragem: Int) {

    constructor(coragem: String) :
            this(
                coragem.split(":")[0],
                coragem.split(":")[1].toInt()
            )
}
```

Para estas duas propriedades a história termina aqui. Elas são inicializadas e nada mais vai ocurrer. Estas variáveis não serão alteradas durante o tempo de vida destes objectos. A questão agora é em que aspect usando `init` poderiamos tirar algum beneficio?

### Init

O uso de init é mais aconselhado para quando queremos chamar funções de inicialização ou por exemplo queremos definir propriedades extra que não fazem parte do construtor. Estas propriedades são calculadas durante a inicialização após a assignação das propriedades definidas pelo construtor. E desta forma alterando a classe `House` para ter mais funcionalidades, podes fazer o seguinte:

```
class ImmutableExtraHouse(
    val cor: String,
    val vagaGaragem: Int,
    val checkinTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

) {

    constructor(coragem: String) :
            this(
                coragem.split(":")[0],
                coragem.split(":")[1].toInt()
            )

    val lotteryTicket: String

    val checkoutTime = checkinTime.plusDays(2)

    private val id:UUID

    init {
        lotteryTicket = Random.nextInt(1000, 2000).toString()
        id = UUID.randomUUID()
        if(vagaGaragem==0) {
            throw RuntimeException("Not able to get a free spot!")
        }
    }
}
```

O que é importante de salientar aqui é que `init` permite que mais do que nada e na maioria dos casos, que nós podamos utilizar e implementar validações customizáveis. Utilizando anotações, obviamente que sempre podemos implementar as validações mais comuns mas esta é uma razão importante para usar o `init`. Outra razão é para implementarmos assignaçṍes complexas de variáveis e manter o código legível e fazer tudo isto durante a inicialização dos objectos. O melhor disto tudo é que em nenhum momento fui obrigado a utilizar `var`. Esta é efectivamene a razão principal para usar `init`. Após a inicialização pelo construtor podemos ainda assignar valores de uma forma complexa utilizando funções, a propriedades imutáveis. O código continua legível e não somos obrigados a usar `var` en nenhum momento.

### Data classes

A tua pregunta não está relacionada com data classes, mas para poder visualizar um example, eu marquei todos estes exemplos com `data class` e fiz um programa para ver isto em acção:

```
@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(House("yellow", 10))
    println(ImmutableHouse("yellow:10"))
    println(ImmutableExtraHouse("yellow:10"))
}
```

### Conclusão

No terminal podemos ver o seguinte resultado:

```
House(cor=yellow, vagaGaragem=10)
ImmutableHouse(cor=yellow, vagaGaragem=10)
ImmutableExtraHouse(cor=yellow, vagaGaragem=10, checkinTime=2024-02-03T12:44:18.668397253)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

E desta forma vemos que tudo funciona e que o uso de mutabilidade não foi necessário.

Importante recordar que se introduzirmos vagaGaragem com valor `0` o runtime vai falhar como esperado. Também important salientar é que as propriedades criadas for do construtor não fazem parte da função `toString` e por isso não aparecem no terminal.

Eu fiz um examplo completo para mostrar as diferenças e podes encontrá-lo [aqui](https://github.com/jesperancinha/jeorg-kotlin-test-drives/blob/main/jeorg-kotlin-crums/jeorg-kotlin-crums-1/src/main/kotlin/org/jesperancinha/ktd/crums1/constructors/BuildingConstructors.kt)

### Saber Mais

Podes encontrar mais informação sobres estes temas nas seguintes fontes:

1. [Constructors in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors)
2. [Data classes in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)